# ngRepeat directive's alias as throwing error - AngularJS 1.5.3 / Ionic 1.3

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to get the processed collection in scope, once filter is applied, so that to update the pagination using alias as in ngRepeat, but which is throwing error even though 'filtered' is not an keyword.

HTML

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="item in Items | filter:custname 
| filter: applyDateFilter('order_date',globalModels.fromdate, globalModels.toDate) as filtered 
| pagination: currentPage * itemsPerPage | limitTo: itemsPerPage" class="my-item item-text-wrap">
```

Whereas for custname, I have added $scope.watch for "custname" and in there using filterFilter able to get the filtered list, like below:

```
   $scope.filtered = filterFilter($scope.Items, term);
```

But the date filter code is different, doing date comparision and returning boolean, so not sure how to get filtered list there.

Date Filter sample:

```
   if (orderDt >= fromDt)  {
        return true;
   }
```

ERROR:

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(26794)] "Error: [ngRepeat:badident] alias 'filtered| pagination: currentPage * itemsPerPage | limitTo: itemsPerPage' is invalid --- must be a valid JS identifier which is not a reserved name.
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/ngRepeat/badident?p0=filtered%7C%20pagination%3A%20currentPage%20*%20itemsPerPage%20%7C%20limitTo%3A%20itemsPerPage
            at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13438:12
            at Object.ngRepeatCompile [as compile] (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:42074:15)
            at applyDirectivesToNode (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22224:32)
            at compileNodes (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21626:15)
            at compileNodes (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21638:15)
            at compileNodes (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21638:15)
            at compileNodes (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21638:15)
            at compileNodes (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21638:15)
            at compileNodes (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21638:15)
            at compile (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21525:15)", source: file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js (26794)
```

Comment: the filter has to be applied before the alias_expression; you can't apply the filter after the alias, the alias must always reflect the current state of the repeat.  In other words, `as filtered` ***must*** be the **last** clause in the `ng-repeat`.

Comment: @Claies I tried changing the alias as the _last_ clause in the ng-repeat `item in Items | filter:custname |  filter: applyDateFilter('order_date',globalModels.fromdate, globalModels.toDate) | pagination: currentPage * itemsPerPage | limitTo: itemsPerPage as filtered ` but it is returning `$scope.filtered` as undefined in the controller part